# Smart TV causes blank screen

Tags: fedora, terminal

Fedora 23

I have a Samsung smart TV. My computer's VGA is connected to a KVM extender and the HDMI is connected to the TV. Generally this works okay because I can use the computer or watch video from the computer on the TV.

Here is the problem:
This will happen this way every time.

1) I log off the computer and the screen blanks after a while.

2) I turn off the TV and go to bed.

3) If I turn the TV on first the next day the computer screen is blank and a reboot is necessary to get it back.CTL-ALT-F2 allows me to log in and reboot from the command line.

4) If I log onto the computer first and then turn on the TV everything works fine, however when I turn on the TV the computer screen does flicker.

Comment: This seems to me like an issue with the KVM extender but a few tests would be needed to clarify that.  Try the same setup on a different computer and OS to see if it does the same thing.